# On hover, change another element that is not near

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm attempting to change `#header` **height** when `.nav-link a` is hovered. I've searched information and it's mostly for affecting child elements and I haven't figured out how to affect something outside of the element.

```
<div id="header">
    <ul>
        <li class="nav-link"><a href="#1">Item 1</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link"><a href="#2">Item 2</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link"><a href="#3">Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: There's no difference for whether the element is near or far. Just write `$("#header").css("height", whatever)`.

Comment: If you can't get it working, you need to post your code.

Comment: @Barmar was attempting to do it with pure css

Comment: in css you cannot select a parent, you can only go down the DOM. You need javascript. jQuery makes it easy. You have your answer below i believe :)

Comment: @bryan If you wanted a pure CSS solution, you shouldn't have put jquery in the tags.

Comment: You can actually do it in CSS if you set your `#header`'s height via `min-height`, and then grow the child's height on hover (which will then grow the parent). Added bonus, the child is larger, so the hover region is as the user would expect. I'll formalize this probably tomorrow, maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.nav-link a').on('mouseover', function(){
    $('#header').css('height', '500px');
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pmyrLvxc/1/

If you don't know the ID of the header for some reason, but you know how far above the target is from the item the event occurs on, you can also do:

```
$(this).parent().parent().css('height', '500px');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pmyrLvxc/3/

Comment: Was attempting to do it just with CSS, but this is definitely an appropriate solution, thank you.

Comment: @bryan it's impossible in CSS, unless you use the checkbox hack